# Laravel Mobile API Using JWT

Tags: api, laravel, jwt

I'm sorry i'm newbie for API

I have a laravel project and i want to create API to connect my laravel database to mobile app, so i try to use jwt on my composer

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
```

after that i adding my route this code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
        Route::post('logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');

        Route::get('test', function(){
            return response()->json(['foo'=>'bar']);
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my login function on controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

After that i'm using POSTMAN to check the response of my API, i insert url localhost:8000/api/login

but i'm getting token error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53
```

What must i do? where i must create the token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting JWT tokens and CSRF tokens mixed up. This issue has nothing to do with JWT, despite the "token" term.

Laravel, by default, [requires a `_token` value](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection) to be passed with every `POST` request to prevent [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

You can include this with your requests, or you can disable CSRF protection for your API by editing `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`'s `$except` value.

Comment: @yudijohn Take a look in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`. And read the documentation I linked.